# ¿Cómo usar INDEX en postgrsql?

Tags: postgresql

Hola tengo una tabla en postgresql con 300.000 registros, cada registro tiene un campo que se llama perfil, son números entre 1 y 43 que se pueden repetir quisiera usar `index`  en ese campo. ¿Cual sería la mejor manera? ya que use

```
CREATE INDEX perfiles ON sys.tablas (campotabla)(INTEGER)
```

y al hacer consultar de un perfil exacto me demora 13 o 15 segundos igualmente

uso esta consulta:

```
 SELECT * from sys.tabla where campotabla = 43
```

Comment: Por favor, añade a tu pregunta la definición de la tabla y la consulta que estás usando. Todo como texto. COn esto podremos ayudarte a revisar el desempeño que comentas

Comment: Ejecuta la sentencia de esta forma: ``EXPLAIN SELECT * from sys.tabla where campotabla = 43`` y nos compartes la salida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu indicas que la columna `perfil` tiene sólo 43 valores posibles. Esto significa que la selectividad promedio de una consulta con predicado igualitario (`WHERE perfil = ...`) es del 2.32% pudiendo ser más alta o más baja, dependiendo del histograma de la tabla.

Ahora bien, en promedio dicha consulta estaría recuperando 7000 filas (300000 / 43) lo que puede ser pesado para tu servidor, especialmente si la tabla tiene muchas columnas (o si tiene columnas pesadas).

Una selectividad del 2.32% no es mala para un índice, pero muchas veces PostgreSQL prefiere leer directamente el heap, saltándose el índice. Ocurre que muchas veces el cache ya podría estar parcialmente poblado (contiene la mayor parte de las páginas del tablespace necesarias), por lo que las operaciones I/O adicionales serían mínimas. Tal vez el motor PostgreSQL está haciendo esto y desestima el índice.

Por un lado, ¿cuántas filas encuentra el predicado `perfil = 43`?

En cualquier caso, es recomendable que actualices el histograma de la tabla, y que luego obtengas el plan de ejecución de tu consulta SQL, usando `EXPLAIN ...`.

Si agregas esta información podremos entender mejor el caso.